# What is the reason for returning undefined voluntarily?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Why would you want to return undefined?
for example in this discord.js code example

```
client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
if (!interaction.isCommand()) return;

const { commandName } = interaction;

if (commandName === 'ping') {
    await interaction.reply('Pong!');
} else if (commandName === 'server') {
    await interaction.reply('Server info.');
} else if (commandName === 'user') {
    await interaction.reply('User info.');
}
});
```

Isn't returning undefined usually a sign something is wrong? So why would I return undefined voluntarily?
Any clearer examples would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Lots of standard APIs return `undefined`. The function you posted *always* returns `undefined`, as far as I can tell.

Comment: It's not about *what* you return, it's about exiting as early as possible.

Comment: In your example, I'm assuming.. `interactionCreate` is an event, sometimes these events can be a command `isCommand()`, but sometime it might not be, maybe another event handler is responsible here,  as such the function is terminating early because it not a command, so no point in checking any further.  IOW: Is this event for me, No -> Ok lets not go any further.

Comment: "*Isn't returning undefined usually a sign something is wrong?*" wait, where did you get that from? [`Array#find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) returns `undefined` when there is nothing that matches, thus treats the value as completely valid (it's part of its codomain). [`Map#get()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/get) will also return `undefined` for a legitimate reason - the key you ask for does not exist. `undefined` is not an error value. Not always.

Comment: All functions in JavaScript `return undefined` by default even if you omit a return statement. If you include the return keyword but don't qualify it, it still returns undefined. The goal of the line in this function is simply to return early so the rest of the function body is not executed.

Comment: Another nice feature of early termination is avoiding indentation, if we didn't early terminate the code would be more like -> `if (interaction.isCommand()) { //lots of indented code }`  , of course you don't have to indent code, but if you don't your code will hurt lots of people eyes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't about returning undefined, the return statement is simply a `guard clause`.
Guard clauses serve the main purpose to exit a function if certain criteria aren't met.

In this case, the reason for the guard clause is to only allow command interactions to go through, and to simply ignore button or selectmenu interactions.

Comment: so basically if the if statement is false, everything after the return doesn’t run? and if it’s true, it will run?

Comment: @WeirdGirlGamer opposite - `if (true)` will trigger the return and exit the function `if (false)` will not and thus continue the function.

Comment: If the if statement is true, whetever you put right after it runs.
because you put "return" right after it, that tells the code to stop running anything in the brackets afterwards.

So if the if statement condition is met, anything after the return doesn't run.